# unwanted log messages on console rc.local ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, server, printing

I activate rc.local service in ubuntu server 18.04: all working fine but more unwanted messages about all operation of rc.local are printed on syslog (this is ok) and **on the console** also I am not logged in (and this is unwanted).

How I can stop the printing of this messages ?

The messages printed on the console are only relative to info or warning about the rc.local service: for example, if I run from rc.local a program and this generate an error or a warning, all this is printed in the syslog and on the screen of the console (usualy show the login prompt but also when I am logged in) and this is particularly annoying when I am editing some script.

Thank in advance,

Emilio

Comment: `dmesg -n 1`or `dmesg -n alert` Both prevents all messages, except emergency (panic) messages, from appearing on the console.

Comment: I tried dmseg -D on grub cfg but it did not work ...

Comment: this is meant as command in ypur Terminal/Console.

Comment: yes, I put dmesg -n0 into /etc/rc.local and now it write no more warning but only errors ... dmeseg -D into rc.local don't work for me ...